# how to switch between 2.4GHz and 5GHz

Tags: android

I am creating an android app which provide information about wifi network like current frequency, ssid, bssid, link rate , downlink etc. my wifi is working on 2.4GHz channel, so all the informations are coming on the basis of 2.4GHz channel, now I want to get information in 5GHz channel. 
Is any way to switch my network from 2.4GHz to 5GHz frequency channel by using my app?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is the hardware problem. 
If your device and hotspot support 5GHz, it will work on 5GHz automatically.

Comment: OK,my problem is that if i want to connect only with 5GHz channel, and if 5 GHz is not available then WiFi is automatically switched off. is this any way to implement at least this scenario.

Comment: @anis.ajmeri unfortunately that's not possible